# jquery validation using remote to check email is already exists or not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am using jquery validator plugin to call ajax function i am using remote method to check the email is already exists or not in my database but i am getting error when i using ajax call.
This is inside my validate function

```
 "email": {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "/adminuser/store"

            },
```

This is my route

```
 Route::post('/adminuser/store', 'Admin\AdminUserController@store')->name('admin.storeadminuser');
```

This is inside my controller

```
$email_exists = Admin::where('email',$request->email)->exists();
        //echo $email_exists;
        if ( $email_exists ) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; }
        exit;
```

The error is

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://birdys.app/adminuser/store?email=karthigamm1995%40gmail.com 404 (Not Found)
﻿
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Add post method in remote like,

```
remote: {
        url: "/adminuser/store",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            email: function() {
              return $( "#email" ).val();
            }
        }
}
```

[Remote-method docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Comment: Try `url: "adminuser/store",` remove the starting `/` from URL

Comment: When i try this it shows          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Change it:

```
Route::post('/adminuser/store', 'Admin\AdminUserController@store')->name('admin.storeadminuser');
```

to

```
Route::get('/adminuser/store', 'Admin\AdminUserController@store')->name('admin.storeadminuser');
```

as the default method of `ajax()` is `get` and your route is defined as `post`. So change it to `get` and try again.

Or define the `type: "post"` in your remote ajax call.

Comment: is it route problem my route is inside a group function `Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){    Route::post('/adminuser/update/{id}', 'Admin\AdminUserController@update')->name('admin.updateadminuser');});`

Comment: so whats the answer